# Drawing a line above first NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nstablecellview

How can I draw a single line above my NSTableCellView?

I understand that on iOS I might use a section header but I'd rather not use something like NoodleKit just for the dark line.

Some alternatives I've thought of that I don't like:

1) Custom background image just for the first row with the dark line drawn.

2) Add a 1px black line as a custom cell as the first cell in the NSTableView.

Is there any better solution?